# How to create a custom slackware "live" dvd?

Tags: iso, slackware

I usually use a slackware-15 setup DVD as "livecd". Is more fast than other real live cd and contain a ssh daemon.
When I use it as livecd I did those steps

step1: give an easy root password

```
echo -e'password\npassword\n' |passwd root
```

step2: start networking

```
dhcpcd -q -4 eth0
```

step3: start dropbear (ssh)

```
/etc/rc.d/rc.dropbear start
```

my question is: is possible to create a custom iso of 15.0 which
make automatically those 3 steps?
How to start? Thanks

personally I tried those steps

```
cp -av /mnt/cdrom /tmp/tmpdir
```

then I go to tmpdir and extract the initrd.img (is a cpio xz compressed file)

```
cp initrd.img initrd.xz
xz -d initrd.xz
mkdir pro1
cd pro1
cpio -i -d -m -H newc --no-absolute-filenames  < ../initrd
```

I start to modify the root fs with my changes

```
vim etc/rc.d/rc.S
ROOT=/tmp/tmpdir installpkg rsync...
```

I save the modified initrd

```
sudo find . -print|sudo cpio -o --owner root:root -H newc | sudo xz -9 > ../initrd.img
```

I made the iso

```
mkisofs -o /tmp/slackware-dvd.iso   -R -J -A "Slackware Install"   -hide-rr-moved   -v -d -N   -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table   -sort isolinux/iso.sort   -b isolinux/isolinux.bin   -c isolinux/isolinux.boot   -eltorito-alt-boot -no-emul-boot -eltorito-platform 0xEF   -eltorito-boot isolinux/efiboot.img   -m 'source'   -V "SlackDVD" .
```

testing the iso on a vm and..

[image]

[IMG][https://i.imgur.com/CbNlo0J.png[/IMG]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iT4V.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found!

Instead of xz the old good gzip even on Slackware 15 works fine.

For decompress and extract I use

```
mkdir tmpdir
cd tmpdir
cpio -dvim < ../initrd
```

For create the image
instead of this line

```
sudo find . -print|sudo cpio -o --owner root:root -H newc | sudo xz -9 > ../initrd.img
```

I use this

```
find . -print|sudo cpio -o --owner root:root -H newc |sudo gzip -9  > ../initrd.img
```

The system boot, with rsync, ip assigned from dhcp and a password for root access.

[image]